# Completing DNS changes for Let's Encrypt

Tags: dns, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

My ACME client output the following:

```
Add the following TXT record:
[Wed Feb 22 11:39:28 EST 2017] Domain: '_acme-challenge.xxxx.ca'
[Wed Feb 22 11:39:28 EST 2017] TXT value: 'some_text_here'
```

I'm trying to figure out, where exactly to put this in my domain configuration.

I currently have this `TXT` value for my domain:

`v=spf1 ip4:some_ip_here/18 ?all`

Do I just append the ACME client data here? If so, is there a specific syntax?

**Update #1**

Decided to call my domain registrar and apparently, I need their help to finalize this.

I had to give them both domain and TXT values to configure, which they did. Their provided interface didn't have the options to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually changed the domain to another registrar that had an interface where the TXT records could be added.

However, since my domain uses an A record with the IP of my VPS, the TXT record method doesn't work (no DNS services on my VPS).

I had to revert to having the ACME client write the content it needed on a publicly accessible folder on the server and have the domain validated that way.